# Foreign keys - database design

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

during db design I found folowing case and I am not sure if I handled that in correct way. So there is my db schema:

[image]

This schema contains data about products that run on given servers. Server can be shared among multiple customers. Table ProductServer tells us that given product has been installed on given server.

Since combination of product/server can be used by multiple customers (server can have multiple customers), I created another table Instance, that contains additional info to ProductServer row. It contains information about which customer uses that product and its priority.

I do not use any persistence framework, so I wrote all fetching functions manually.

My problem is: currently I have query, that joins all tables:

```
 SELECT * FROM ProductServer ps
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p ON ps.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Server s ON ps.server_id = s.server_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ServerCustomer sc ON s.server_id = sc.server_id
 **LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c ON sc.customer_id = c.customer_id**
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Instance i ON ps.ps_id = i.ps_id
 **LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c2 ON i.customer_id = c2.customer_id**
```

In my SQL, you can see rows marked with **, I had to join one table two times in one query, I am not exactly sure, but I feel that this can be bad idea/bad design of db.

I had an idea to split ProductServer and Instance to one table, but since ProductServer table will have perhaps 100k row, I felt that its better to split this table between two smaller tables.

Please can you tell me whether this is badly designed and forward to some sources where I can figure out how implement this problem in better way?

**Edit:**
I need to fetch all Customers for given Server because I need to fetch all data to Java object`s. Thats why I need table Customer joined with ServerCustomer and also joined Customer with Instance table in one database query.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is to re-arrange your joins and only join to `Customer` once. Not entirely clear whether your current conditions should be combined by an `AND` or an `OR`. I'm going with `AND` here:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductServer ps
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p ON ps.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Server s ON ps.server_id = s.server_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ServerCustomer sc ON s.server_id = sc.server_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Instance i ON ps.ps_id = i.ps_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c ON sc.customer_id = c.customer_id
                            AND i.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

You can do this because joins aren't necessarily between two tables - they're between table sources which may themselves already be the result of other joins. So, in the above, when we reach the final `ON` clause, we're joining `{ProductServer, Server, ServerCustomer, Instance}` on the left to `{Customer}` on the right, and we can reference any columns from any of those tables as part of our join conditions.

Comment: The reason why I did those two joins is that because I use this query to fetch all those data into Java objects.

So I need to have all customers object in server object and I also need to have customer object in instance object.